# DB2 SQL - Customize Decimal Points Based on Value

Tags: sql, db2, decimal

I am looking to mask decimal fields with custom decimal points. Here is an example as to what I am looking to do.

```
----------------------------------------------
-fieldName----fieldValue----result after mask-
----------------------------------------------
 505          2             5.05
 76812        5             .76812
 8185         3             8.185
```

All of these columns are stored as an `INT` or a `DEC` without any decimal points.

Maybe `DB2` has something similar to the `FORMAT()` `SqlServer` function? That masks the value and doesn't do exactly what I would like but still, it's a start.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use built in math functions and divide by power of 10.

```
CAST(fieldName AS DOUBLE) / POWER(10, fieldValue)
```

If you are storing these numbers this way because the numbers are just too big then alternatively you can convert them to `VARCHAR`, then you can use `SUBSTR()`.

Comment: I like this option! I will be testing it out shortly.

Comment: Thanks! We used something along the lines of this. For everyone using this, beware this turns the value into a `float`. It will be somewhat difficult to deal with if you're not careful.

Answer (score 1):

What about a maths solution?

```
 cast(fieldName as decimal(12,6)) / power(10, fieldvalue)
```

The cast is just to make sure it is a decimal field (the definition needs to be big enough for your data)